# best_in_place not showing update until after refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, best-in-place

I followed the somewhat out of date railscast on best_in_place and also read the gem documentation. I am using version 2.1.0.

I'm using best_in_place on just one field:

```
<%= best_in_place feedback, :status, type: :select, :collection => [["New", "New"], ["Emailed", "Emailed"], ["Flagged", "Flagged"], ["Closed", "Closed"]]%>
```

I have this in my controller:

```
respond_to :html, :json

def update
  @feedback = Feedback.find(params[:id])
  @feedback.update_attributes(feedback_params)
  respond_with feedbacks
end
```

On submit it reverts to the previous value but if you refresh the page you can see that the update did work. I just want to get the update to show immediately.

Comment: You are sending back a response made with `feedbacks` which is, I guess, a list of `Feedback` records. Try to return only the new value of the field updated, something like `render json: { params[:field].to_sym => @feedback.send(params[:field]) }`

Comment: That doesn't change anything. the field I'm changing is :status so I'd change :field to :status in your example right? feedbacks is my index of Feedback records. I'm doing the update from the index so it wants to respond_with the same view but updated.

Comment: Oh right, that works. Surprised that works in "singular" since it's rendering an index. Great. You want to put that in an answer zishe and I'll tick it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as following:

```
def update
  @feedback = Feedback.find(params[:id])
  @feedback.update_attributes(feedback_params)
  render json: { params[:field].to_sym => @feedback.send(params[:field]) }
end
```

This allows you to use this `update` action for every allowed fields defined in `feedback_params`. So you could send requests like:

```
params[:field] = 'title'
params[:value] = 'New Title Given!'
# or
params[:field] = 'content'
params[:value] = 'New Content for this feedback Given!'
# etc.
```

---

If your `update` is used by other kind of updates than `best_in_place`, you might not have the `params[:field]` and `params[:value]` defined. You can easily test their presence before render as json:

```
def update
  @feedback = Feedback.find(params[:id])
  @feedback.update_attributes(feedback_params)
  if params[:field].present? # means that the action is used via `best_in_place`
    render json: { params[:field].to_sym => @feedback.send(params[:field]) }
  else
    respond_with feedbacks
  end
end
```